# Story or book with a large facility at the sub-solar point of a tidally locked planet

Tags: story-identification

I have a distinct memory of reading a science-fiction book or short story in which a major confrontation between two characters (possibly a female protagonist and a male antagonist with a long history that once included friendship?) happens in a facility located at the sub-solar/sub-stellar point on a tidally locked world.

I probably read this book pre-2005, and my memory gives it a tone and style that would match writing from the 1990s — I thought for a while that it was a Vernor Vinge story, and the scene I remembered is similar to one at the end of *Tatja Grimm’s World*.

The *Tatja* scene takes place at a mountain-peak observatory, however, and the tidal-locking elements of the setting feel like a core part of the memory — the idea that the terminator line would influence the location of population centers (e.., by pushing most activity towards the terminator line or creating separate dayside and nightside cultures), is part of my big-picture memory of the world structure. One of the characters may have been planning to make an expedition to the nightside of the planet.

Any suggestions as to what story or book I’m remembering? I don’t think it matches any of the suggestions in [Is there any sci-fi story about intelligent extra-terrestrial life on a tidal locked planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37456/is-there-any-sci-fi-story-about-intelligent-extra-terrestrial-life-on-a-tidal-lo)

Comment: You're clear that the population lived on the terminator?  That means that this facility is cooled, else it would otherwise be too hot?

Comment: @DavidW: I thought so, but that point does seem problematic. It’s possible that the terminator-line detail was instead that there was a division in populations between day-side and night-side. I’ll edit that into the question.

Answer (score 4):

The scene and the "tide locked" condition are reminiscent of *Jack of Shadows* by Roger Zelazny -- including divided lightside and darkside populations, science based in the day and magical in the night.

The similar scene actually plays through most of chapters 7 and 8 (which is a substantial fraction of this short novel, due to Zelazny's talent for telling four or five pieces of a story at once).

This was as Jack (posing as "Jonathan Shade" to gain a position as a lecturer at an unnamed university) was completing his (lightside) computer research leading to recovery of the (darkside) Lost Key of Kolwynia.  He had a female colleague who had helped him find some ancient books, though she wasn't present when the Borshin caught up with him (having ended their partnership after finding new blood stains on two of the books she'd helped him find), and one might be forgiven for thinking the computer lab was at the subsolar point.

Jack had just been found out by one of the university's administrators, a man name Quilian, when a creature called the Borshin, sent by the Lord of Bats (a night-sider) finally caught up to him.  At this point, then (p. 85 in my 1970s vintage paperback copy), Jack gives one of the most memorable soliloquies in fantasy fiction (at least in my opinion):

> "I am Jack of Shadows!" he cried out.  "I am Shadow Jack, the thief who walks in silence and in shadows.  I was beheaded in Igles, and rose again from the Dung Pits of Glyve.  I drank the blood of a vampire and ate a stone.  I am the breaker of the Compact.  I am he who forged a name in the Red Book of Ells.  I am the prisoner in the jewel.  I duped the Lord of High Dudgeon once, and I will return for vengeance upon him.  I am the enemy of my enemies.  Come take me, filth, if you love the Lord of Bats or despise me, for I have named myself Jack of Shadows!"

Both lightside and darkside were maintained at habitable temperature by the "Shield" -- a magical construct maintained in turn about by the darkside Powers under the truce agreement called The Compact.

There was no ladder in this scene, but later in the book, when Jack journeyed to the center of the Earth where the Great Machine kept the world still, I recall a very long stairway -- or, much earlier, there was a tall tower at High Dudgeon where Jack did a few of things he spoke above in the quote above.

Comment: That potentially rings a bell. Two more details I’m remembering: Does the computer lab facility have a name, and is there a long ladder involved with the scene?

Comment: I don't recall -- it's probably been thirty-five or forty years since I last read it.  I'll try to remember to look it up (I have a paper copy at home).  If this *is* it, you should certainly reread it -- it's one of the finest crossovers between SF and (mostly) fantasy I recall reading.

Comment: @RLH Okay, I've edited in more details and a quote you're almost certain to remember if this is the correct book.

Comment: Thanks! I don’t think it’s this, but I am intrigued and will seek out the book.